# RewriteRule - take all urls with dash

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I need to redirect all urls with dash to a specific page.
For example:
`site.com/this-url` to `site.com/page.php?url=this-url`

RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+-.+)$ page.php?url=$1
```

just hang http. No response.

What is wrong and how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, you may have an infinite loop.

```
RewriteCond $0 !^page\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+-.+)?$ page.php?url=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

Now:

- The RewriteCond avoids matching the rule if you already requested page.php
- The `QSA` flags appends all the query parameters from the original request to the rewritten request
- The `B` flag escapes the backreference `$1` so that it can safely be used as a query paramater
- The `L` flag is not strictly necessary, but avoids evaluating other rewrite rules when this one is matched

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this option:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page\.php
RewriteRule - page.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,B,QSA]
```